# Let indentation inside proc notation

Tags: haskell, indentation

I have the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

test :: Int -> Int
test =
  proc x -> do
    let x = case x of
              3 -> 2
              2 -> 1
              _ -> 0
    returnA -< x

test2 =
  proc x -> do
    let x =
      case x of
        3 -> 2
        2 -> 1
        _ -> 0
    returnA -< x
```

test compiles, but test2 does not parse. Is it possible to have the case on a separate line after the =?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is unrelated to `proc` notation. The `case` must be at least as indented as one character after the start name being bound by `let`.

For example, this compiles:

```
test x =
  let y =
       case x of
         3 -> 2
         1 -> 1
         _ -> 0
  in ()
```

and so does this:

```
test2 x =
  let abcdefghi =
       case x of
         3 -> 2
         1 -> 1
         _ -> 0
  in ()
```

but this doesn't:

```
test3 x =
  let abcdefghi =
      case x of
        3 -> 2
        1 -> 1
        _ -> 0
  in ()
```

because the `case` is at the same level as the first character of `abcdefghi`.